# connecting two tables with foreign keys in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi in my senario there is a table with 4 columns and im trying to create another table with connection to the first table but i dont whay im getting this error in logcat

```
2019-10-28 01:04:00.853 29812-29812/com.test.fastfoodfinder E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting notes_main=testeststststststststs
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: notes (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO notes(notes_main) VALUES (?)
```

so i have created a class for my data base and this is what i have done

```
public class RestaurantDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final static String DATABASE_NAME = "FastFood_DataBase.db";
    private final static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;



    private final static String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
            "(" + COLUMN_RESTAURANT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," +
            COLUMN_RESTAURANT_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_RESTAURANT_ADDRESS + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_RESTAURANT_TYPE + " INTEGER, " +
            COLUMN_RESTAURANT_IMAGE + " INTEGER);";


    private final static String CREATE_TABLE_NOTES = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_NOTES +
            "(" + COLUMN_NOTES_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + COLUMN_NOTES + " TEXT," + "FOREIGN KEY (" + COLUMN_NOTES_ID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME +"(restaurant_id) ON DELETE CASCADE)";


    public final static String DELETE_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

    public RestaurantDBHelper(@Nullable Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA FOREIGN_KEYS = ON;");
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_NOTES);
    }


    @Override
    public void  onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(DELETE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(COLUMN_RESTAURANT_NAME, restaurant.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_RESTAURANT_ADDRESS, restaurant.getAddress());
        values.put(COLUMN_RESTAURANT_TYPE,restaurant.getType());
        values.put(COLUMN_RESTAURANT_IMAGE, restaurant.getType());

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        db.close();
    }

    public void addNotes (Restaurant restaurant) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(COLUMN_NOTES,restaurant.getNote());

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME_NOTES,null,values);

        db.close();
    }
```

and

```
public class RestaurantContract {
    public static class EntryRestaurants {
        public final static String TABLE_NAME = "restaurants";
        public final static String COLUMN_RESTAURANT_ID = "restaurant_id";
        public final static String COLUMN_RESTAURANT_NAME = "restaurant_name";
        public final static String COLUMN_RESTAURANT_ADDRESS = "restaurant_address";
        public final static String COLUMN_RESTAURANT_TYPE = "restaurant_type";
        public final static String COLUMN_RESTAURANT_IMAGE = "restaurant_image_type";
        public final static String COLUMN_RESTAURANT_NOTE_ID = "note_id";

        public final static String TABLE_NAME_NOTES = "notes";
        public final static String COLUMN_NOTES_ID = "notes_id";
        public final static String COLUMN_NOTES = "notes_main";

        public final static int RESTAURANT_TYPE_DELIVERY = 1;
        public final static int RESTAURANT_TYPE_SITDOWN = 2;
        public final static int RESTAURANT_TYPE_TAKEAWAY = 3;
    }
}
```

im kind a new in android so any help would be appreciated,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your issue is with the **onCreate** method. This ONLY runs when the database is created, it does not run every time the App is run.

The easiest solution, assuming that you do not need to keep any existing data, is to either delete the App's data or to uninstall the App. After doing either rerun the App and the new table will be created as the **onCreate** method will then run.

Furthermore it is no use turning FOREIGN KEYS on in the onCreate method. FOREIGN KEYS need to be turned on every time the App is run. To fix this, override the **onConfigure** method and then use `db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);`

- this is just a convenient alternative to using `db.execSQL("PRAGMA FOREIGN_KEYS = ON;");`, so if you prefer you could use this when overriding the onConfigure method.

e.g. add this method to the RestaurantDBHelper class :-

```
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onConfigure(db);
    db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
}
```

**However**, you will then have issues when trying to add notes as the child will be set to null and thus their will not be a link/map/association/reference between the added note and the restaurant.

You need to use something like :-

```
public long addNote(String note, long restaurantId) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NOTES,note);
    values.put(COLUMN_NOTES_ID,restaurantId);
    return db.insert(TABLE_NAME_NOTES,null,values);
}
```

**BUT** then you may then have an issue as to determining the id of the restaurant.

**BUT** then you may then encounter a further issue in that you could only have one note per restaurant as the column used to reference the restaurant is defined as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY and is therefore is a UNIQUE column (the same value can only be used once (an exception is null as a null is considered to be unique to another null)).

If the requirement is for one note per restaurant then there is no need for the separate table the relationship is a **one to one** relationship so the value can be stored in the restaurant table.

If you want a restaurant to have multiple notes (**one to many** relationship) then you should not make the column INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, INTEGER would suffice. Then a number of notes could reference the same restaurant.

If you wanted a note to be able to be be applied to a number of restaurants then you'd use a third mapping/line/reference/associative table (other name probably also exist). Such a table would have two columns one to reference the restaurant and the other to reference the note. You would then have a **many to many** relationship between restaurants and notes (a note could be used by many restaurants and a restaurant could use many notes).

You may find [The 3 Types of Relationships in Database Design](https://database.guide/the-3-types-of-relationships-in-database-design/) helpful.

Comment: thanks for the reply really help full but know im facing the issue that my note table is not getting any thing as you mentioned and this is my add method ////public void addNotes (Restaurant restaurant) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(COLUMN_NOTES,restaurant.getNote());
        values.put(COLUMN_NOTES_ID,COLUMN_RESTAURANT_ID);

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME_NOTES,null,values);

        db.close();
    }

Comment: You need to look at the log there will either be a data mismatch error or a Foreign Key constraint conflict. In short you are trying to put **restaurant_id** (the column name) into the *notes_id** column, **it won't go**. The **id** of the restaurant will be an integer and it **MUST** be the **id of an existing restaurant** as could be obtained when inserting the restaurant (*see **addNote** in the answer it returns the note's id as a long*) or you need to get it from the database by querying for the restaurant. If you have issues, then you should ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

You have enabled foreign key constraints and thus must have a unique primary key for the foreign key to reference.

https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes

says

> If the database schema contains foreign key errors that require looking at more than one table definition to identify, then those errors are not detected when the tables are created. Instead, such errors prevent the application from preparing SQL statements that modify the content of the child or parent tables in ways that use the foreign keys. Errors reported when content is changed are "DML errors" and errors reported when the schema is changed are "DDL errors". So, in other words, misconfigured foreign key constraints that require looking at both the child and parent are DML errors. The English language error message for foreign key DML errors is usually "foreign key mismatch" but can also be "no such table" if the parent table does not exist. Foreign key DML errors are reported if:

```
The parent table does not exist, or
The parent key columns named in the foreign key constraint do not exist, or
The parent key columns named in the foreign key constraint are not the primary key of the parent table and are not subject to a unique constraint using collating sequence specified in the CREATE TABLE, or
The child table references the primary key of the parent without specifying the primary key columns and the number of primary key columns in the parent do not match the number of child key columns.
```

Given that you never give the `restaurant_id` a value when you inserting a restaurant then the primary key of the `restaurants` is probably always `null` and thus not unique

(Yes according to https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-primary-key/ to make the current version of SQLite compatible with the earlier version, SQLite allows the primary key column to contain NULL values. )

So I would say the solution is to create `restaurant` entries with a unique primary key value when you insert a restaurant or get the database to generate a unique value creating the the `restaurant` table with the line:-

`private final static String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
"(" + COLUMN_RESTAURANT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
....`

One way to confirm this is download `FastFood_DataBase.*` files using `Device Explorer` in your app's database directory and then open it up in https://sqlitebrowser.org/ on your computer to confirm the contents.